# If $f:M(n\times n) \to Sym(n \times n) \subset M(n\times n)$, Show $Sym(n \times n)$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R^{n(n-1)\over{2}}}$

Tags: linear-algebra, smooth-manifolds, diffeomorphism

If $f:M(n\times n) \to Sym(n \times n) \subset M(n\times n)$,

Show $Sym(n \times n)$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R^{n(n-1)\over{2}}}$

Where $Sym(n \times n)$ is the set of symmetric matrices

I'm not quite sure where to start.

Comment: Note that $Sym(n \times n)$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ of dimension $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ (Try to specify a basis for the space)

Comment: Why isnt it an n-dimensional vector space? It would make more sense actually that it was of dimension $\mathbb{R^{n(n+1)\over{2}}}$  because its specified by that many scalars

Comment: Yes, you’re right. My mistake, it should indeed be of dimension $n(n+1)/2$

Comment: That said, it will be diffeomorphic to the corresponding $\mathbb{R}^m$ instead of the one you wrote in your question

Comment: Thank you, it was given to me incorrectly and I was confused. Is there a way to upvote your answer or something? I don't know how to give you credit for the help

Comment: Don’t worry about that. Just glad I could help